# Google Authenticator in Yast

Tags: opensuse, pam, two-factor-authentication, yast

I've successfully added 2FA with [Google Authenticator package](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=security&package=pam-google-authenticator) on openSUSE Leap 42.1 for Display Manager, `login`, `sudo` and `su`. I have to enter a verification code from Android app every time I use these tools (both for my main user and root).

However, when I e.g. try to install software via GUI with Yast2 there's no field to enter the code. I enter my root password and Yast's window freezes (probably waiting for the code). The reason is that Yast2 uses `su`. So when I comment out the line with Google Authenticator in `/etc/pam.d/su` I can open Yast and install software, change system settings, etc.

How can I make Yast2 ask me for verification codes?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having a similar problem to one I have encountered with AppleID accounts with Two-Factor enabled running on legacy OSX versions.  Try appending the code to the end of your password string with no spaces.